# Is there any other way to achieve solr clustering other than solr-cloud

Tags: solr, liferay, liferay-6, solrcloud

I am using solr 4.3 which is integrated with liferay6.2 and liferay has some integration problem when it comes to solr cloud. So how can I achieve clustering especially the fault tolerance feature without using solr-cloud. Is there any other alternative to solr cloud.

Answer (score 0):

Solr's old way of scaling is still in place. It is now called *"Legacy Scaling and Distribution"*, you will find it under exactly [this topic in Solr's official documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Legacy+Scaling+and+Distribution).

There it is quoted

> This section describes how to set up distribution and replication in
>   Solr. It is considered "legacy" behavior, since while it is still
>   supported in Solr, the SolrCloud functionality described in the
>   previous chapter is where the current development is headed. However,
>   if you don't need all that SolrCloud delivers, search distribution and
>   index replication may be sufficient.
>
> This section covers the following topics:
>
> - Introduction to Scaling and Distribution: Conceptual information about
>     distribution and replication in Solr.
> - Distributed Search with Index Sharding: Detailed information about
>     implementing distributed searching in Solr.
> - Index Replication: Detailed information about replicating your Solr
>     indexes.
> - Combining Distribution and Replication: Detailed information about
>     replicating shards in a distributed index.
> - Merging Indexes: Information about combining separate indexes in Solr.